# Novel (I think French) about time travelling robots kidnapping people

Tags: story-identification, novel, robots

It doesn't take place on Earth. Suddenly one day robots appear and kidnap the inhabitants of the planet. They are like tribal level of technology. Some of them go and try to find the source and discover a portal that the robots come out of and some other robot or giant head or something that the other robots protect and claim is their leader while the big head / robot thing says it does not know what these robots are but that they come from the future.

There are some other details too but the story ends with the main characters going into the future portal and killing the big head guy thing there cause he is the evil guy in the future commanding the robots to go and kidnap people to use their brains for fuel or something like that.

The name of the novel was the name of the big robot head thing. I think the book was written over 50 years ago at least.

Comment: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2125/23243 :-D

Comment: What kind of tribe? American Indigenous People? Vikings? Cleveland Indians?

Comment: Like American Indigenous People level of tech. I remember one of the plot points is a main character is given something they can use on the big robot head thing to kill it, they go to the big robot head and talk to it and it says it is innocent please don't kill me I would never do this, it must be a misunderstanding go to the future and kill the real villain sort of thing and they go along with it. It harvests the brains cause it needs them to survive due to decaying. I think the cover of it was blue?

Answer (score 2):

This could very well be *Les Hommes-machines contre Gandahar* by Jean-Pierre Andrevon.
Everything in your description fits, except the name of the novel; Gandahar is the name of the planet, not the big head thing.

It has a Wikipedia page, in French: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Hommes-machines_contre_Gandahar.
Hope this helps! If not, there is an English page about the movie that was made from the book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film)